# Joint distribution of difference of normals

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution

Consider the following three independent random variables, $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$, $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)$, and $X_3 \sim N(\mu_3,\sigma^2_3)$.

Now let me define the pairwise differences as $\delta_{12} = X_1-X_2$, $\delta_{13} = X_1-X_3$, and $\delta_{23} = X_2-X_3$.

I know that these pairwise differences are easy to calculate as normal random variables, e.g.,

$$\delta_{ij}\sim N(\mu_i - \mu_j, \sigma^2_i + \sigma^2_j)$$

but are we able to calculate the joint distribution of $\delta_{12},\delta_{13},\delta_{23}$ in closed form?

In other words, what is the joint distribution of $p(\delta_{12},\delta_{13},\delta_{23}| \mu_1, \mu_2,\mu_3,\sigma^2_1,\sigma_2^2,\sigma_3^2)$?

Or do we need to place more assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write
\begin{align}
\Delta :=
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{12} \\
\delta_{13} \\
\delta_{23} 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 - X_2 \\
X_1 - X_3 \\
X_2 - X_3 
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0  \\
1 & 0  & -1 \\
0 & 1  & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
X_3 
\end{bmatrix} =: AX, 
\end{align}
then $\Delta \sim N_3(AE(X), A\operatorname{Cov}(X)A^T)$ by [Affine transformation property of MVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation).  Given that
\begin{align}
E(X) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\
\mu_3 
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
\operatorname{Cov}(X) 
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & \sigma_2^2  & 0 \\
0 & 0  & \sigma_3^2 
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
can you finish the calculation?

Comment: Indeed I can. Thank you so much

Comment: Is this a degenerate normal distribution?

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, because $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2 < 3$.

Comment: Given that fact, is there a way to work around it so that I can still sample from the distribution? Or rather does that create an issue?

Comment: It means that you don't need to consider the joint distribution of $\delta_{12}, \delta_{13}, \delta_{23}$.  Instead, just consider the joint distribution of any two of the three.  It's similar to in ANOVA, you set up a baseline level, and focus only on the difference between other levels and this fixed level.

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but is there any issues working with degenerate distributions? As in, is it okay to still use this distribution to make inference about $\delta_{12}, \delta_{13},\delta_{23}$?

Comment: @JohnSmith As long as you are sufficiently cautious when working with it, there should not be issues.  But as I said above, degenerated distribution essentially tells you that you don't really need that many dimensions and some dimension reduction should be done beforehand.  For example, working with $(X, X)' \sim N_2\left((0, 0)', \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)$ is no different from working with $X \sim N(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial. The marginal means and variances remain the same, i.e. exactly as you have computed them. All you need to know is to calculate the off-diagonal of the variance-covariance matrix. To do so, this simple (useful) formula tells you what you need to know:

$$ \text{var}(X_1 - X_2) = \text{var}(X_1) + \text{var}(X_2) - 2 \text{cov}(X_1, X_2) $$

Comment: This only characterizes the mean vector and the covariance matrix but does not say what the joint distribution is.

Comment: The OP has already stated that the differences are marginally normal, hence we need only characterize the covariance matrix to complete the problem.

Comment: @AdamO OP eventually asked for joint distribution.

Comment: @AdamO, marginal normality + mean vector + covariance matrix does not imply a joint distribution, or does it?

Comment: @RichardHardy I probably learned my math facts in 1st year prob/stats in a different order than others, but I assumed the joint dist'ns of normals - under constraints already implied by OP - was already established.