# Joint posterior distribution of differences

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, differences

I have data $x_1,...,x_n$, $y_1,...,y_m$ and $z_1,...,z_p$ where
$$x_1,...,x_n\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$$
and
$$y_1,...,y_m\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)$$
and
$$z_1,...,z_p\sim N(\mu_z,\sigma^2_z)$$

Now let's assume I want to take a Bayesian approach and place the following priors: $p(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)\propto (\sigma^2_x)^{-1}$, $p(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)\propto (\sigma^2_y)^{-1}$, and $p(\mu_z,\sigma^2_z)\propto (\sigma^2_z)^{-1}$. Given these priors, I know what the posterior distribution is, but more importantly, I know that the conditional marginal distributions are

$$\mu_x|\sigma^2_x,x_1,...,x_n\sim N(\bar{x},\sigma^2_x/n)$$ and
$$\mu_y|\sigma^2_y, y_1,...,y_m\sim N(\bar{y},\sigma^2_y/m)$$ and
$$\mu_z|\sigma^2_z,z_1,...,z_n\sim N(\bar{z},\sigma^2_z/p)$$

where $\bar x$ is the average of the $x$'s. Similarly, for the case of the $y$'s and $z$'s.

I am interested in deriving the joint distribution of $\mu_x-\mu_y$, $\mu_y-\mu_z$, $\mu_y-\mu_z$ . Does the following approach make sense?

We know that the conditional posterior distribution of $\mu_x$ is
$$p(\mu_x|\sigma^2_x,x_1,...,x_n) = N\left(\bar x, \frac{\sigma^2_x}{n}\right)$$

and similarly for $p(\mu_y|\sigma^2_y,y_1,...,y_m)$ and $p(\mu_z|\sigma^2_z,z_1,...,z_p)$.

Now, define
\begin{align}
    \Delta :=  \begin{bmatrix}
        \delta_{xy}\\\\
        \delta_{xz}\\\\
        \delta_{yz}
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \mu_x-\mu_y\\\\
        \mu_x - \mu_z\\\\
        \mu_y - \mu_z
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0\\\\
        1 & 0 & -1\\\\
        0 & 1 & -1
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        \mu_x\\\\
        \mu_y\\\\
        \mu_z
    \end{bmatrix} =: 
    A\mu,
\end{align}
then we have that $$\Delta|\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z, x_1,...,x_n, y_1,...,y_m, z_1,...,z_p \sim N_3\left(A \mathbb{E}(\mu), A\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(\mu)A^T\right)$$
where
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}(\mu) = \begin{bmatrix}
        \bar{x}\\\\
        \bar{y}\\\\
        \bar{z}
    \end{bmatrix} \text{    and     } \mathbb{C}\text{ov}(\mu) = \begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma^2_x/n & 0 & 0 \\\\
         0 & \sigma^2_y/m & 0 \\\\
         0 & 0 & \sigma^2_z/p
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

So my ultimate questions are the following:

1. Would the distribution above for $\Delta$ be the correct joint conditional posterior distribution of the differences?
2. And if so, would the appropriate strategy to obtain posterior samples from $\Delta$ be to first samples $\sigma^2_x, \sigma^2_y,$ and $\sigma^2_z$ from their joint posterior distribution?
3. And if so for number 2) does the joint posterior distribution of $\sigma^2_x, \sigma^2_y,$ and $\sigma^2_z$ have a closed form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The conditional analysis is correct (assuming posterior conditional independence between $\mu_x,\mu_y,\mu_z$), as already indicated in the [answer to your earlier question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595908/7224)!
2. Simulating $σ_x$, $σ_y$, and $σ_z$ from their joint (marginal) posterior distribution, then $\mu_x,\mu_y,\mu_z$ from the corresponding conditional posterior is correct. However, if simulating from the (marginal) posterior proves complex, a Gibbs sampling approach may be preferable. But...
3. ...since
   $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left\{-\left[n(\bar x_n-\mu_x)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x_n)^2\right]\big/2\sigma^2_x\right\}\,\frac{\text d\mu_x}{\sigma_x^{n+2}}\\\propto\exp\left\{-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x_n)^2\big/2\sigma^2_x\right\}\sigma_x^{-n-1}$$
   and the equivalent closed forms for $σ^2_y$, and $σ^2_z$, the marginal posterior on $(\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z)$ is available.

Comment: Thanks for confirming 1) and 2). For 3) I understand that the marginal posteriors for the $\sigma^2$s are available in closed form (inverse-gammas), but are you implying that that joint (marginal) of the $\sigma^2$'s is not available in closed form (I was hoping that it reduced some how to, say, and inverse wishart)? Also, is there any reason or probability rule I am breaking by sampling from the marginals of each $\sigma^2$ and then plugging those into the joint distribution of $\Delta$ to obtain a posterior sample of $\Delta$ from the corresponding Normal distribution?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple questions, but if I interpret your answer correctly, that is to say I have $p(\Delta, \sigma^2_x, \sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z|data) = p(\Delta| \sigma^2_x, \sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z,data) p( \sigma^2_x, \sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z|data)$ and here $ p(\sigma^2_x, \sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z|data) = p( \sigma^2_x|data)p( \sigma^2_y|data)p( \sigma^2_z|data)$ by independence?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was extremely to walk through that.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. As I was going to code this up, I realize I don't recognize the kernel of the last expression in your 3). At first I had assumed it was inverse-gamma, however inside the exponential you have $\sigma^2_x$ and outside the exponential you have $\sigma_x^{-n-1}$. In order to get it to match upI assume a bit of reworking is needed. I want to confirm that the marginal of $\sigma^2_x$ is Inverse-gamma($n/2 - 1/2, \Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})^2/2$)

Comment: Sorry if this is an obvious question, but in your last expression where you integrate out $\mu_x$, how come you don't have to integrate out with respect to $\Delta$, i.e., why is $d\mu_x$ instead of $d\Delta$? I would have assumed I needed to do that since I am working with $p(\Delta, \sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2,\sigma^2_z|data)$ and want to obtain the marginals for the $\sigma^2$ terms. Or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: The marginal on $(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ associated with the joint $p(\mu_x,\ldots,\sigma_z|data)$ is also the marginal on $(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ associated with the marginal on $(\mathbf{\Delta},\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ associated with the joint $p(\mu_x,\ldots,\sigma_z|data)$.

Comment: I get it now! I was forgetting about the original posterior distribution of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and was only thinking in terms of $\Delta$.

Comment: If I wanted to calculate the posterior predictive distribution of the differences, would it make sense to just sample from the posterior predictive distributions associated with independent posterior distributions (i.e., $p(\tilde x |x), $p(\tilde y | y), $p(\tilde z | z) $, sample from those, and then subtract the corresponding samples to get an estimate of the posterior predictive distribution? Or would it make more sense to first sample the $\sigma^2$'s, then sample from $\Delta|...$, and then sample from the likelihood of the difference based on those samples?

Comment: The issue I have there is that I don't know what the likelihood I would be plugging the samples into in that case.

Comment: If it helps, I formalized this question into a new post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/597632/posterior-predictive-distribution-of-the-difference

Comment: Based on your degenerate comment here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596205/joint-posterior-distribution-of-differences/596241?noredirect=1#comment1104354_596241, is this multivariate normal also degenerate?