# Posterior predictive distribution of the difference

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

My question here is related to the following question I posted here:
[Joint posterior distribution of differences](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596205/joint-posterior-distribution-of-differences/596241?noredirect=1#comment1104354_596241)

With respect to that last question, what I want to discuss is how to appropriately sample from the posterior predictive distribution of the differences, i.e., the distribution $p(x^*-y^*, x^*-z^*,y^*-z^*|x,y,z)$. I assume to get this distribution I would need to calculate something like
$$p(x^*-y^*, x^*-z^*,y^*-z^*|x,y,z)=\\
\int_\Delta\int_{\sigma^2_x}\int_{\sigma^2_y}\int_{\sigma^2_z}p(\Delta,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z| x, y, z)p(x^*-y^*, x^*-z^*,y^*-z^*|\Delta,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z x, y, z)d\Delta d\sigma^2_xd\sigma^2_yd\sigma^2_z$$

I know, as a general strategy in the case of a general posterior predictive distribution, say
$$p(x^*|x) = \int_\Theta p(x^*|\theta,x)p(\theta|x)dx,$$
if you want to sample from $p(x^*|x)$, one strategy is to first sample a posterior draw $\theta$ and then to plug that $\theta$ into $p(x^*|\theta,x)$ and then sample an $x^*$ (i.e., a posterior predictive draw) from $p(x^*|\theta,x)$ which is just the same type of distribution as the likelihood.

Now returning to my question, I figured I could first sample $\sigma^2_x$, then sample $\sigma^2_y$, then sample $\sigma^2_z$, and then sample $\Delta$ (i.e., get posterior samples), and then to plug those posterior samples into $p(x^*-y^*, x^*-z^*,y^*-z^*|\Delta,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z| x, y, z)$ and to take a sample from that likelihood to get a posterior predictive draw. However, where I am stumped, is what the form of the likelihood $p(x^*-y^*, x^*-z^*,y^*-z^*|\Delta,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z x, y, z)$ actually is.

My alternative thought was to sample independently from $p(x^*|x)$, $p(y^*|y)$, and $p(z^*|z)$ (which I know how to do) and to then subtract those samples, i.e., $x^*-y^*$, $x^*-z^*$, and $y^*-z^*$, but my concern is aren't the those samples $x^*-y^*$, $x^*-z^*$, and $y^*-z^*$ independent of one another, while a sample of $p(x^*-y^*, x^*-z^*,y^*-z^*|\Delta,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z x, y, z)$ is not?

Or could I use the following strategy, first sample $\sigma^2_x$, then sample $\sigma^2_y$, then sample $\sigma^2_z$, and then sample $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, and $\mu_3$ (i.e., get posterior samples), and then take a sample from
$$\begin{pmatrix}x^*-y^*\\
x^*-z^*\\
y^*-z^*\end{pmatrix}\sim N_3\left(A\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1\\
\mu_2\\
\mu_3\end{pmatrix}, A\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^2_x & 0 &0\\
0 & \sigma^2_y & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sigma^2_z\end{pmatrix}A^T\right)$$

where $$\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^2_x & 0 &0\\
0 & \sigma^2_y & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sigma^2_z\end{pmatrix}$$ is the associated covariance matrix, and $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1& -1 &0\\
1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
is a matrix of contrasts.

Comment: The second strategy works just fine. For justification google search “law of the unconscious statistician”

Comment: @Taylor, I updated my question. Do you think the last strategy is correct?

Comment: You didn't mention the last strategy or anything about normality the last time I read this. Looks like you have your question answered, anyway, so I won't go any further.

Answer (score 1):

The predictive distribution$$p(x^*-y^*, z^*-x^*,y^*-z^*|\Delta,\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z x, y, z)$$is a Normal  distribution as a linear transform of a Normal  vector:
$$
\delta\equiv\left[\begin{matrix}
x^*-y^*\\ z^*-x^*\\y^*-z^*
\end{matrix}\right]
=\underbrace{\left[\begin{matrix}
1 &-1 &0\\-1 & 0& 1\\0 &1 &-1
\end{matrix}\right]}_{\mathbf D}
\times
\left[\begin{matrix}
x^*\\ y^*\\z^*
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Hence
$$\delta=\left[\begin{matrix}
\delta_1\\\delta_2\\\delta_3
\end{matrix}\right]\sim\mathcal N\left(
\left[\begin{matrix}
\mu_x-\mu_y\\ \mu_z-\mu_x\\\mu_y-\mu_z
\end{matrix}\right],
\mathbf D\, \text{diag}(\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z)\,\mathbf D^\top
\right)\tag{1}$$
but this Normal is degenerate since $\delta_1+\delta_2+\delta_3=0$ with probability one. To generate from (1), one thus need (only) generate $(\delta_1+\delta_2)$ and derive $\delta_3=-\delta_1-\delta_2$.

Since
$$\mathbf D\, \text{diag}(\sigma^2_x,\sigma^2_y,\sigma^2_z)\,\mathbf D^\top=\left[\begin{matrix}
\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y &-\sigma^2_x &-\sigma^2_y\\
-\sigma^2_x &\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_z &-\sigma^2_z\\
-\sigma^2_y &-\sigma^2_z &\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y
\end{matrix}\right]$$
the marginal of the pair is
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
\delta_1\\ \delta_2\\
\end{matrix}\right]\sim\mathcal N\left(
\left[\begin{matrix}
\mu_x-\mu_y\\ \mu_z-\mu_x
\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}
\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y &-\sigma^2_x\\
-\sigma^2_x &\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_z
\end{matrix}\right]\right)$$

Comment: Are the variances in your covariance matrix correct? Shouldn't you take $Cov([x^*, y^*,z^*]^T)$ which is a diagonal matrix of individual variances rather than sums of two variances?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Also, can you fix the degenerate issue by simply changing $\delta_2$ to $\delta_2 = \mu_x-\mu_z$? You currently have it as $\delta_2 = \mu_z-\mu_x$.

Comment: I understand in the case you have shown its degenerate since knowing 2 of the random variables tells you the third, but in the case I describe, i.e., $d_2=\mu_x-\mu_z$ I don't understand why this is the case. If I took $\delta_1 + \delta_2 + \delta_3$ it does not sum to 0, i.e., $\delta_1 + \delta_2 + \delta_3= 2\mu_x-2\mu_z$

Comment: Perhaps, I don't understand what the definition of degenerate is here. Is it for any linear combination of the $\delta$'s, if they sum to 0 then it's degenerate?

Comment: This means that the random 3D-vector $(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3)$ belongs to a 2D plane with probability one.

Comment: I think I get it then. If you can write one of the components of the random vector as as a linear combination of the others, then its a degenerate normal, correct?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that your comment is more of a caution on how to sample from this multivariate distribution, but not that it is problematic (I read this the wrong way!). So I'm fine to use a degenerate multivariate normal as long as aI can sample from it correctly. And in this case I am using R's mvrnorm package which seems capable of doing so.